# How to fix 'Whoops, session expired' error from Zencart Payment

Tags: php, session, e-commerce

I have an install of zencart on my server and I am trying to pay via paypoint.net, but everything i do so, it comes back as session expired on zencart. The payment has gone through fine, but needless to say, the order hasn't been processed.

Googling the problem people say to add this in

suhosin.session.encrypt off

for php

I have done this and confirmed with phpinfo() and it still doesn't work. Does anyone else have any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be passing back the session ID from the payment gateway to Zen Cart, if you aren't doing so already.

See the following extract from init_sessions.php

```
if (isset($_POST[zen_session_name()])) {
  zen_session_id($_POST[zen_session_name()]);
} elseif ( ($request_type == 'SSL') && isset($_GET[zen_session_name()]) ) {
  zen_session_id($_GET[zen_session_name()]);
}
```

Perhaps your problem lies elsewhere, but I know I've got caught up by not doing this in previous integrations with OS Commerce/Zen Cart.